# Animation help, Python 3.2 with Pygame

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I'm currently making a side scrolling game. I drew a stick figure and drew an animation of him going right when the 'W' key is help down. The problem is I don't know how to make the original drawing (the one where he's holding still) go away when I'm holding down W so they overlap each other. Here's my code:

```
def pulse_ninja(screen,x,y):

    #Head
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen,PULSEPURPLE,[14+x,-8+y,15,15],0)

     #Legs
    pygame.draw.line(screen,WHITE,[20+x,17+y],[25+x,27+y],4)
    pygame.draw.line(screen,WHITE,[20+x,17+y],[15+x,27+y],4)

     #Body
    pygame.draw.line(screen,PULSEPURPLE,[20+x,16+y],[20+x,-2+y],4)

     #Arms
    pygame.draw.line(screen,PULSEPURPLE,[20+x,3+y],[30+x,18+y],4)
    pygame.draw.line(screen,PULSEPURPLE,[20+x,3+y],[10+x,18+y],4)

    #Sword
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            pygame.draw.line(screen,GREEN,[30+x,18+y],[35+x,0+y],3)
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            pygame.draw.line(screen,GREEN,[30+x,18+y],[50+x,16+y],3)

def ninja_animate_right(screen,x,y):

     if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
         if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            # Head
            pygame.draw.ellipse(screen,PULSEPURPLE,[16+x,-6+y,15,15],0)

            # Legs
            pygame.draw.arc(screen,WHITE,[10+x,0+y,15,30], 3*pi/2, 2*pi, 2)
            #pygame.draw.arc(screen,WHITE,[20+x,17+y],[15+x,27+y],4)

            # Body
            pygame.draw.line(screen,PULSEPURPLE,[20+x,16+y],[25+x,-2+y],4)

            # Arms
            pygame.draw.line(screen,PULSEPURPLE,[20+x,3+y],[30+x,18+y],4)
            pygame.draw.line(screen,PULSEPURPLE,[20+x,3+y],[10+x,18+y],4) 
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            pygame.draw.line(screen,GREEN,[30+x,18+y],[35+x,0+y],3)
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            pygame.draw.line(screen,GREEN,[30+x,18+y],[50+x,16+y],3)
```

and when I call them I just have them one line after another

```
pulse_ninja(screen,x,y)

ninja_animate_right(screen,x,y)
```

I'm guessing I need a while loop? Is there a stop module? Say I want to run a function and then STOP it after a condition is met. That's essentially what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a small advice, in your class, define a state: moving left, right, stopping, etc. In your movement field, draw things according to the current state of your character. So the only thing that you need to do is:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_w:
        character.state = WALKING

if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_w:
        character.state = STANDING
```

in your move function, you will look at the current state, and draw accordingly.
I recommend the use of classes, since the variables and functions will be much more organized.

Comment: Thank you, I don't fully understand classes yet, but I'm studying them right now. This helped a lot.